# How to use refs React in internal component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs, refs

I was using reference in my react 16 for integrating ChartJs but the problem that I am getting is the reference is working in APP.js, Routing.JS but not working in internal components...

App.js

```
componentDidMount(){
let ctx=this.weight;
console.log(ctx);
 }
render() {
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <RouterIndex />
    <canvas className="chart" ref={ref=>this.weight=ref}>

    </canvas>
  </React.Fragment>

);
```

}

Output in console

> `<canvas class="chart"></canvas>`

which is correct

Inside RouterIndexComponent.js

```
 let weight=""
 useEffect(()=>{
    let ctx=weight;
    console.log(ctx);
})
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={CovidNormal}  />
                <Route exact path="/country/:country" component={Country} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
        <canvas className="chart" ref={ref=>weight=ref}>

        </canvas>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

Again output in console

> `<canvas class="chart"></canvas>`

which is again correct but inside CovidNormal.js component

```
componentDidMount(){

let ctx=this.weight;
console.log(ctx);
}
render()
{
   return(
   <canvas className="chart" ref={ref => this.weight = ref}>

   </canvas>
   )
}
```

The output is `undefined`
Why it is so.